# Dropdown menu not 100% when mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a navbar with dropdown menus but they don't go 100% when displayed on mobile. I made it so that all columns with class="col-' are displayed 100% when the screen is smaller than 768px (Mobile First). But the dropdown menus don't follow this rule as where the parent menu does. How can I fix this? Thx in advance!

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Fullscreen backgrounds with centered content">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col-12 navbar-0">
        <div class="col-10 col-container col-center-block navbar-1">
            <div class="colom col-4 home"><strong><a href="index.php">HOME</a></strong></div>
            <div class="colom col-4 dropdown aanbod">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">BERLAMO</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content col-12">
                    <a href="http://berlamo.be/index.php/webdesign-2">ONE-PAGE-WEBSITES</a>
                  <a href="http://berlamo.be/index.php/huis-te-koop">HUIS TE KOOP</a>
                    <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4">PORTFOLIO</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="colom col-4 contact"><strong><a href="http://berlamo.be/contactform.html">CONTACT</a></strong></div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <style>

/*#FB4D4D red, #414F71; blue*/
    /* Navigation */

    .navbar-0 {
        height: auto;
    }

    .navbar-1 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #414F71;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .home,
    .contact {
        padding: 0px;
    }

    /* Dropdown Button */
    .dropbtn {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background-color: white;
        color: #414F71;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        min-width: 160px;
        z-index: 1;
margin-top: 10px;
    }
    /* Links inside the dropdown */

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: #414F71;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
      border-top: 1px solid #FB4D4D;
    }
    /* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

    .show {
        display: block;
        border: none;
    }

    /*2e drop*/
    /* Dropdown Button */

    .dropbtn2 {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background-color: white;
        color: #414F71;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

    .dropdown2 {
        position: relative;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

    .dropdown-content2 {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        min-width: 160px;
        z-index: 1;
margin-top: 10px;
    }
    /* Links inside the dropdown */

    .dropdown-content2 a {
        color: #414F71;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
      border-top: 1px solid #FB4D4D;
    }
    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

    .dropdown-content2 a:hover {
        background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
    /* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

    .show {
        display: block;
        border: none;
    }

/*Einde drop*/

    button:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
/*function myFunction(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}*/
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    /*If you bind 2 onclick then only last one will fire*/

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
            removeShow("dropdown-content");
        }

        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn2')) {
            removeShow("dropdown-content2");
        }
    }

    function removeShow(className) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }

    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When changing a elements position to Absolute, a block level element will no longer fill 100% width of it's parent, but instead will only fill as much space as it's children.

There are 2 ways you can solve this.

1. Add 100% width to the absolute element

   width: 100%;
2. Set the absolute elements left and right to 0

   left: 0;
   right: 0;

Once you add this, the remaining space to the left and right is due to your parent elements having padding and margins on the left and right.

You will need to remove these on mobile for the menu to stretch full screen width.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't quite follow I'm afraid... I added a 100% width to .dropdown-content but it doens't change anything. Did I put it at the wrong class?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the dropdown menus didn't go 100% was because there was a padding of 10px on the div above (navbar-1). So I removed the left and right padding and now everything goes 100%.